# Birt Report - Chart Coloring

Tags: birt

I've got a issue with the coloring of by bars in the chart of a Birt Report.

As you can see in the picture below, the Legend is rendered properly - all items have unique colors, but in the graph itself all bars are colored equally (so if I would remove the labeling of the x-axis the legend would not help at all).

[image: Birt ReportChart]

Has anyone experienced a similar behavior as well and knows how to fix it?
Even in the preview everything looks alright:

[image: Chart Preview]

used BIRT Version is 3.7.2

many thanks,
Martin

Comment: This is weird. The "Color by" option of the serie is correctly set to "Categories" on your screenshot. Is this blue gradient present in "Series palette"? If so, try to remove it to see what happens. Otherwise there might be a script applying this color. Do you have any chart script in your report?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer - actually I figured out why this happened: I tried to re-use an existing diagram by copying it from another report design file - this seem to cause troubles, at least when it comes to colouring the bars. After creating the chart from scratch everything was alright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by re-using the chart (copy/past) from a former report design file. Everything else was fine, just the coloring was messed up.

After re-creating the chart from scratch everything was alright